# How can I Generate a Rig for my Character?

Tags: mesh, rigging

So i wanted to rig my mesh similarly to how the Mixamo Y-bot works, with the limbs rolling on the "ball" joint. But when i try to replicate this it just stretches the mesh instead of allowing it to roll over the joints smoothly. How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: don't use automatic weight, but parent to "bone"

Comment: Thank you I’ll try that!